Unit Test Not Providing Expected Result
My unit test inside MainViewModelTest.kt is not working. It seems like the line         _recentTvShowList.update { duplicateRemoverSet.toList() } is not updating. I've mockked out the repository and the dao so I can't figure out why it is not working.
MainViewModelTest.kt
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainViewModelTest {
    private lateinit var repository: TvShowsRepository
    private lateinit var dao: TvShowCheckerDao
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by lazy { MainViewModel(repository) }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()

    private val testModules = module {
        single<TvShowsRepository> { mockk<TvShowsRepository>() }
        viewModel { MainViewModel(get()) }
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class MainDispatcherRule(private val dispatcher: TestDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()) :
        TestWatcher() {
        override fun starting(description: Description?) = Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)

        override fun finished(description: Description?) = Dispatchers.resetMain()

    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        repository = mockk(relaxed = true)
        dao = mockk(relaxed = true)
        startKoin { modules(testModules) }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Test
    fun `tests getRecentTvShows() returns list of recent tv shows`() = runTest {
        val repository: TvShowsRepository = mockk()
        val tvShow1 = TvShow(
            id = 1,
            description = "Show 1",
            title = "Description 1",
            airDate = "https://example.com/show1.jpg"
        )
        val tvShow2 = TvShow(
            id = 2,
            description = "Show 2",
            title = "Description 2",
            airDate = "https://example.com/show2.jpg"
        )
        coEvery { dao.getRecentTvShows() } returns listOf(tvShow1, tvShow2)
        coEvery { repository.getRecentTvShows() } returns flowOf(listOf(tvShow1, tvShow2))
        viewModel.getRecentTvShows()

        val expectedList = listOf(tvShow1, tvShow2)
        viewModel.recentTvShowList.test {
            assertEquals(expectedList, awaitItem())
        }
    }
}

Function tested in MainViewModel.kt
suspend fun getRecentTvShows() {
        val duplicateRemoverSet = mutableSetOf<TvShow>()
        repository.getRecentTvShows().collect { tvShowList ->
            tvShowList.forEach {
                duplicateRemoverSet.add(it)
            }
        }

        _recentTvShowList.update { duplicateRemoverSet.toList() }
    }

Full MainViewModel.kt
@OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
class MainViewModel(
    private val repository: TvShowsRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _searchText = MutableStateFlow("")
    val searchText = _searchText.asStateFlow()

    private val _isSearching = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isSearching = _isSearching
        .onStart { getTvShows() }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            false
        )

    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _isEpisodesLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isEpisodesLoading = _isEpisodesLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _selectedTvShow = MutableStateFlow<TvShowExtended?>(null)
    val selectedTvShow = _selectedTvShow.asStateFlow()

    private val _selectedSeason = MutableStateFlow(listOf<TvShowSeasonEpisodes>())
    val selectedSeason = _selectedSeason.asStateFlow()

    private val _error = MutableStateFlow("")
    val error = _error.asStateFlow()

    private val _tvShowList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<TvShow>())
    val tvShowList = searchText
        .debounce(1_000L)
        .onEach { _isSearching.update { true } }
        .combine(_tvShowList) { text, tvShow ->
            if (text.isBlank()) {
                tvShow
            } else {
                tvShow.filter { it.searchTvShow(text) }
            }
        }.onEach { _isSearching.update { false } }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
            _tvShowList.value
        )

    private val _recentTvShowList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<TvShow>())
    val recentTvShowList = _recentTvShowList.asStateFlow()

//    init {
//        viewModelScope.launch {
//            getRecentTvShows()
//        }
//    }

    fun onSearchTextChange(text: String) {
        _searchText.value = text
        viewModelScope.launch { getTvShows(text) }
    }

    private suspend fun getTvShows(query: String = ""): List<TvShow> {
        val duplicateRemoverSet = mutableSetOf<Result>()
        try {
            val temp = repository.getTVShows(query).results
            temp.forEach {
                duplicateRemoverSet.add(it)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _error.update { e.localizedMessage ?: "No error found" }
        }
        val tvShowList = AppMapper.mapGetTvShowsApiResultToTvShowList(duplicateRemoverSet.toList())
        _tvShowList.update { tvShowList }
        return tvShowList
    }

    suspend fun getRecentTvShows() {
        val duplicateRemoverSet = mutableSetOf<TvShow>()
        repository.getRecentTvShows().collect { tvShowList ->
            tvShowList.forEach {
                duplicateRemoverSet.add(it)
            }
        }

        _recentTvShowList.update { duplicateRemoverSet.toList() }
    }

    fun insertRecentTvShow(tvShow: TvShow) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertRecentTvShow(tvShow = tvShow)
        }
    }

    fun getTvShowById(tvShowId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                _searchText.update { "" }
                val apiResult = repository.getTVShowById(tvShowId)
                val result = AppMapper.mapGetTvShowByIdApiResultToTvShow(apiResult)
                _selectedTvShow.update { result }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _error.update { e.localizedMessage ?: "No error found" }
            }
        }
    }

    fun getTvShowSeasons(tvShowId: Int, seasonNumber: Int = 1) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _isEpisodesLoading.value = true
            try {
                val apiResult = repository.getTvShowSeason(tvShowId, seasonNumber)
                val result = AppMapper.mapGetTvShowSeasonsApiResultToTvShowSeason(apiResult)
                result.forEach {
                    it.isChecked = repository.getIsWatchedStatus(it.episodeId)
                    it.tvShowId = tvShowId
                    insertTvShowSeasonEpisodesToDB(it)
                }
                _selectedSeason.update { result }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _error.update { e.localizedMessage ?: "No error found" }
            }
            _isEpisodesLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    fun getTvShowSeasonsOffline(tvShowId: Int, seasonSelected: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _isEpisodesLoading.value = true
            try {
                val databaseResult = repository.getTvShowSeasonOffline(tvShowId, seasonSelected)
                _selectedSeason.update { databaseResult }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _error.update { e.localizedMessage ?: "No error found" }
            }
            _isEpisodesLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    private fun insertTvShowSeasonEpisodesToDB(tvShowSeasonEpisodes: TvShowSeasonEpisodes) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.insertTvShow(tvShowSeasonEpisodes)
        }
    }

    fun updateIsWatchedState(episodeId: Int, isWatched: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateIsWatchedStatus(episodeId = episodeId, isWatchedStatus = isWatched)
        }
    }
}


awaitItem() will return the first emitted value in the flow, which is an empty list of TvShow in your case. Could you try using expectMostRecentItem() to get the latest emitted value?
viewModel.recentTvShowList.test {
     assertEquals(expectedList, expectMostRecentItem())
}

